# Display a chart from hook_form_submit

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am writing a Drupal 7 custom module that will collect some form data and then display a chart to the browser based on that data.  I am following examples for generating charts programmatically using the Charts module.  In the code below I am using a sample pie chart just for proof of concept. drupal_render is returning the correct chart code but I cannot find a way to display it to the browser from within hook_form_submit. What am I missing?  Any ideas?

```
function stats_degrees_form_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
  $demo = $form_state['values']['demo'];
  $chart = make_chart($demo);
  print $chart;
}

function make_chart($demo){
  //$degree_csv_array = get_demo_data($demo);
  // build chart
  $chart = array(
    '#type' => 'chart',
    '#title' => t('Pie Chart with data labels (no tooltips)'),
    '#chart_type' => 'pie',
    '#chart_library' => 'google', // Allowed values: 'google' or 'highcharts'
    '#legend_position' => 'right',
    '#data_labels' => TRUE,
    '#tooltips' => FALSE,
  );
  $chart['pie_data'] = array(
    '#type' => 'chart_data',
    '#title' => t('Gender'),
    '#labels' => array('Male', 'Female'),
    '#data' => array(10, 20),
  );
  return drupal_render($chart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way to use hook_form_submit ,
this callback doesn't display anything , it made for custom actions on submit form data and reload form page.

So if you want to display something with datas submitted , use `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` into hook_form_submit , all the values will be passed to form reloaded `$form_state['values']`. You can make 'if' condition into your custom form declaration to display chart if you have values into your field.

Otherwise you can redirect form to antoher page dedicated to chart displaying with `$form_state['redirect']`.

Please read documentation about Form API :
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/form-api
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I will try $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE.  I did see $form_state['redirect'] but I was not sure what to redirect to, another custom module?  Also, in that case I am not sure how to pass all the form data.

Comment: rebuild to TRUE will keep values after submit and allow you to use it into form after it. Redirect define an url to go after submit processing , so you can pass data with GET appending or store it to session variable .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue; I used $form_state['redirect'] like so:

```
function stats_degrees_form_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
  $demo = $form_state['values']['demo'];
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'stats-degrees-chart/' . $demo;
}

function stats_degrees_chart($demo) {
  $chart = make_chart($demo);
  $content['raw_markup'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => $chart,
  );
  return $content;
}
```

Where make_chart is in my question above, that returns drupal_render.